# What does media="print" in CSS linking mean?

Tags: html, css

I found out that for proper working of one of my packages I must add `media="print"` to the link, like here:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="my_href" media="print">
```

But what does `media="print"` do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It means that the styles in that stylesheet will only be applied when a user tries to print your webpage.

This is extremely useful for hiding things like the navigation, comments, sidebars etc. so that a user can simply print the text.

You can even do this inside "normal" CSS files too, using the print media query which basically achieves the same thing, as below:

```
@media print {
    #sidebar, header, footer, #comments {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It is the styling applied to printers, to be more exact, the style applied when you want to print the page.

Read more [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries.asp).